# How to test normal distribution of a variable

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, t-test

I have two data sets:

**1st scenario:**
I measured one metabolite, and I want to test if it is normally distributed to perform a T-test or a non-parametric test.

N1 subjects took drug1, and I measured the metabolite
and N2 subjects took drug2, and I measured the metabolite

To test the metabolite distribution, should I perform the normality test to the total number of available measurements of the entire population(N1+N2) or separately for each group (N1, N2)?

**2nd scenario:**
Similarly, I have a cross-over design study in which the same number (N) of patients took drug1 and, after a wash-out period, took drug2.
In this scenario, should I test the distribution of the metabolite considering all the measurements (2xN measurements) or for each group separately(drug1, drug2)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're just asking a statistics question, this would be better asked on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). However to answer your question, test for normality separately in each of your groups.

Comment: Dear Roy, thank you so much for your reply. I will also note this site for future reference!